# how to stop app store asking for earlier version to download

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app which was supporting iOS 6+

Client changed the design and many things and hence we re-create the app and upload with iOS 8+

Now app is approved and it is on App Store.

When I try to download app on iPhone which have iOS 7 it gives below message.

[image]

***Is there way where I can stop showing this message? I don't want users to use earlier app.***

Comment: It's not nice to prevent past users from using older versions of your app. Unless it is free, you really need to reconsider this.

Comment: @rmaddy : ***that is client decision.. they want to use new app only...*** **don't worry, this app have just 10 downloads in 2 years and they are just client testers** ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have not test before,but you may try this

1. In itunes connect, selected **Pricing and Availability**,then in the bottom
   you can find that **Last-Compatible Version Settings**
2. Deselected any version you do not want Compatible

[image]

Comment: I have done as per your info... it might take several hours to get into effect... I will check that later and accept if it works... thanks for the support...

Comment: Haha,glad to hear that